# Accessing windows registry under GCC/C++

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, registry, mingw

I'm trying to access windows registry using standard windows api.
I'm using mingw c++ compiller.

Please tell why this code crases at line (X)

```
HKEY hKey;
DWORD dwDisp = 0;
LPDWORD lpdwDisp = &dwDisp;
```

<strike>QString value = "String Value";</strike>

```
LONG iSuccess = RegCreateKeyEx(
      HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
      TEXT("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run"),
      0L,
      NULL,
      REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE,
      KEY_ALL_ACCESS,
      NULL,
      &hKey,
      lpdwDisp);

if(iSuccess == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
(X)    RegSetValueEx(hKey, TEXT("1234"), 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)4, 4+1);
}
```

Debugger shows Segmantation fault at this line.

Thank you very much for help. I'm new to windows API.

Comment: You are telling it that you stored the value to write at address 4.  Kaboom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [function description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724884%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) again.

If you want to set the default value for the key you need to do something like this:

```
TCHAR szData[] = TEXT("1234")
RegSetValueEx(hKey, NULL, 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)szData, sizeof(szData));
```

If you actually want to specify the value name:

```
TCHAR szData[] = TEXT("1234")
RegSetValueEx(hKey, TEXT("valuename"), 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)szData, sizeof(szData));
```

The registry has a somewhat confusing terminology. The key in this context basically means "folder". Each folder has a default value, and can contain other values with specified names. You pass null if you want to set the default value, and a string if you want to name the value. These values shows up as "files" in the key "folder" when you look in the register editor.

Comment: @Emil: I meant with the placement of [] in your correction :)

Comment: So it should be TCHAR szData[] = TEXT("1234"); ?

Comment: @David: yes, if you're following Emil's example.

Comment: Thanks, now it doesn't crash :). But when i run it new value in the registry is not created. I checked inside the key : HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run and didn't find my new value. What might be the couse ? Thanks for help.

Comment: Removed HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\ from the key path and now works great. Thanks.

Comment: @Peter: Oh snap. Checked back by chance, and finally realized what you meant. Better late than never, I suppose. (And your right of course, I work mainly in java these days.)

Comment: @Emil: I do the same thing on occasion :)

Answer (score 2):

Casts are bad.

What do you expect `(LPBYTE)3` to do?  Why do you think you need it?

<strike>Isn't that where `value` should be used?  Perhaps as `value.ascii()` or `value.constData()` (depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined)?</strike> (NOTE: `QString value` mysteriously disappeared from the question)

Comment: Maybe he just wants to store the value "3". In that case he either needs to make it a string, or needs to change the value type to REG_DWORD.

Comment: Sorry it was suppose to be the size of the string. If I put there 4 or 5 it still crashes.

Comment: (LPBYTE)4 means that I want to store 4 chars

Comment: @David: that's because you're telling RegSetValueEx to set a string value and passing an invalid pointer (which is now 0x4).  If you intend to set string data, you need to pass it a pointer to a string and the size parameter needs to be the size of the string (including the null character) in bytes.

Comment: @David: No, the size of the data is the sixth argument.  We're looking at your fifth parameter.

Comment: @Ben: I removed the QString line because it only complicated this example. My fault, I should have removed it before posting the whole question. Thanks for help, I'm trying to learn windows API step by step :) ps I described the changes I made in remarks field.

Answer (score 0):

Remove HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\ from the second parameter and it should work fine. 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE should be set in the first param.